# USB On-The-Go - What receptacle types does it support?

Tags: usb, connector, usb-otg

Is it possible to use a USB mini B as opposed to the USB mini AB for USB OTG?

Can I use either USB mini or USB micro and does it need to be type AB or can I just use type B?

Comment: For USB if a device you need to use B, if its a host you need to use A. So if your using OTG and your not using OTG as a host then use the B connector. If the OTG needs to function as a host, then use the AB connector.

Comment: I am wondering if OP is asking such a primitive question, who will be implementing the OTG protocol, which is much more challenging problem?

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Wikipedia [[USB OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go)]

*"An OTG product must have a single micro-AB receptacle and no other USB receptacles.*

*An OTG cable has a micro-A plug on one end, and a micro-B plug on the other end (it cannot have two plugs of the same type). OTG adds a fifth pin to the standard USB connector, called the ID-pin; the micro-A plug has the ID pin grounded, while the ID in the micro-B plug is floating. A device with a micro-A plug inserted becomes an OTG A-device, and a device with a micro-B plug inserted becomes a B-device. The type of plug inserted is detected by the state of the pin ID."*

There are several other sources which have information about USB OTG.

[USB On-The-Go Specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/onthego/otg1_0.pdf)

Comment: Also USB Type-C

Comment: In reality, though, almost all USB OTG devices (smartphones) have non-standard Micro-B receptacles and non-standard Micro-B to Micro-B cables.

Answer (score 1):

> can ı use usb mini b type receptable instead of mini ab, for OTG?

According to [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB-ON-THE-GO) of a Wikipedia page, you should only use a "mini ab" receptacle for On The Go (OTG) complaint USB hosts and devices.  All non-compliant hosts are to use the "mini a" and non-complaint devices are to use the "mini b".

Note, there is an "mini a" type plug and receptacle and a "mini b" type plug and receptacle designed to be incomparable (can not be interchanged accidentally) with one another.  Here are images of the receptacles:

[image][image]

By contrast, the "mini ab" receptacle is designed to accept either "mini a" or "mini b" plugs.  Here is an image of the "mini ab" receptacle:

[image]

A device that has a "mini ab" receptacle is responsible for detecting if the "a" end or the "b" end of a USB cable has been inserted into the "mini ab" receptacle.  This is done using the 5th pin or the ID pin.  This text, from the above Wikipedia link, explains how this works:

> To enable Type-AB receptacles to distinguish which end of a cable is
>   plugged in, mini and micro plugs have an "ID" pin in addition to the
>   four contacts found in standard-size USB connectors. This ID pin is
>   connected to GND in Type-A plugs, and left unconnected in Type-B
>   plugs. Typically, a pull-up resistor in the device is used to detect
>   the presence or absence of an ID connection.

Comment: I have to admit, I too look up this same information from time to time to double check my work.  If you find anything wrong with this answer or if it confuses you ... please post a comment and I will make sure to change the answer accordingly.

Comment: There are Garmin devices that use the ID pin (4 in the above diagrams) as a means to detect that they are being used with their specific power supply devices (usually a Car Cigarette Lighter based unit) - they use a resistor connected between that pin and ground (pin 5) to signal that the PSU can supply more than the normal 500mA of a standard USB connection and also that the Sat. Nav unit **should not switch into the "PC-connection" (USB data-transfer) mode**. This is a PITA in some situations because it makes it impossible to use any other PSU device or extend the lead and use the device.